# How to use setState to update the property of an object inside an array the right way in class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects in the state with the following structure:

```
const arrayOfTests = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "test1",
        description: "test description"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "test2",
        description: "test description"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "test3",
        description: "test description"
    }
]
```

Lets say I find object with id of 3 like this:

```
let object3 = arrayOfTests.find((element) => {
    return element.id === 3;
})
```

And then I edit it like this:

```
object3.description = "new description"
```

I'm kinda confused how to use `setState` to replace/edit the old object 3, with the new updated one.

Comment: you could also use https://github.com/immerjs/immer to simplify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map()` method as shown below.

Inside the callback function, check if the condition `element.id === 3` is true; if it is, return a *new* object. Otherwise, return the current `element` as it is.

```
let newState = arrayOfTests.map((element) => {
    if (element.id === 3) {
       return { ...element, description: "new description" };
    }
   
    return element;
});
```

Pass the array returned by the `map()` method to the state setter function.

```
this.setState({ state: newState });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setState((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  arrayOfTests: prevState.arrayOfTests.map((item) =>
    item.id === 3 ? { ...item, description: "new description" } : item
  ),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({
  arrayOfTests: arrayOfTests.map(item => {
    if (item.id === 3) {
      return {
        ...item,
        description: 'new description'
      }
    }
    return item
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [test, setTest] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "test1",
            description: "test description"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "test2",
            description: "test description"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "test3",
            description: "test description"
        }
    ]);

    const handleUpdate = (index) => {
        const some_array = test;
        var newState =  some_array[index];
        newState.description =  "new description";
        some_array[index] = newState;

        setTest(some_array);
        console.log(test);
    }

return(
      {test.length > 0 && test.map((data, index)=>{ return(handleUpdate(index)}>{data.description})
       })
}  
)
```