# How to update array element using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a checkboxes array with boolean values and I want to update its elements on change. Now instead of filled array `[false, false, false, false, true]` I get `[empty × 4, true]`

```
  const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState([]);
  const [listInfo, setList] = useState([]);

  const getList = async () => {
    const response = await list.get('/list/')
    setList(response.data)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const array = []
    getList().then(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < listInfo.length; i++) {
        array[i] = false
      }
      setCheckboxes(array)
    })
  }, [])

  const handleChangeCheckbox = (event, i) => {
        let isChecked = event.target.checked;
    const array = []
    if (isChecked) {
      array[i] = true
      setCheckboxes(array)
    } else {
      array[i] = false
      setCheckboxes(array)
    }
  }
```

And I call this function:

```
<input key={i} type="checkbox" onChange={e => handleChangeCheckbox(e, i)}></input>
```

How to update elements correctly?

Comment: Use the `map()` method. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845719/how-to-use-setstate-to-update-the-property-of-an-object-inside-an-array-the-righ/68845779#68845779) should give you an idea of how you could do this.

Answer (score 1):

**You created an empty array and replaced your state, that's why you get `[empty × 4, true]`**

You need to spread your existing state before changing an item inside them:

```
  const handleChangeCheckbox = (event, i) => {
    const isChecked = event.target.checked;
    const array = [...checkboxes]  // <-- This line
    if (isChecked) {
      array[i] = true
      setCheckboxes(array)
    } else {
      array[i] = false
      setCheckboxes(array)
    }
  }
```

---

In your last case, it will be similar to this:

```js
const array = [];
array[3] = true;
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Isn't he set his `setCheckboxes` in the `useEffect`?

Comment: oh shoot ! i didn't notice that :-) my bad !

Comment: Haha, Not to worries mate. I'd thank you for your last edit. `users[0]?.[1]?.items` this one.

Comment: No need of if-else` statements as well...it's directly provided by `isChecked` flag.

Comment: That's right, but it's good to stick with his original solution but not to mess around his head with a brand new implementation, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new array from `checkboxes` state. You can use `array#map` to generate new array from `checkboxes` state and update the state at index `i` and `checked` status of checked element.

```
const handleChangeCheckbox = (event, i) => {
    const isChecked = event.target.checked;
    const newArray = checkboxes.map((val, idx) => idx === i ? isChecked: val);
    setCheckboxes(newArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid race condition, use `useState` in following way.

```
const handleChangeCheckbox = (event, i) => {
  const array = [];
  const isChecked = event.target.checked;

  setCheckboxes((checkboxes) => {
    array = checkboxes.slice();
    array[i] = isChecked;
    return array;
  });
};
```

Comment: this keeps appending `true` or `false` to the checkboxes array . But the user wants to update the value of the state based on an index .